# Can one convert pdf to swf dynamically?

Tags: php, file, pdf, flash, converters

Can one convert PDF to SWF dynamically? I have been trying, but it proved to be difficult.

Here is my code:

```
<?php
include('include\settings.php');

$title = "k";
$makeswf= mysql_query("SELECT * FROM books WHERE title = '$title'");
$rows = mysql_num_rows($makeswf);

if ($rows !=0)
{
while($rows = mysql_fetch_assoc($makeswf))
{

//where blocation is the pdf file need to be converted.

$file = $rows['blocation'];

echo exec('D:\wamp\www\dspzlibrary\converter\pdf2swf.exe books\$file.pdf -o books\$file.swf -f -T 9 -t -s storeallcharacters');
}

  }

else
echo"empty";

?>
```

And here is the error I received:

> ERROR Couldn't open books\$file.pdf

Any assistance will be appreciated.

Comment: "here is the code" - I think you might have forgotten to post the code there.

Comment: Code was not formatted as such.  The php tag caused it to be ignored for display.

Answer (score 1):

The error message is telling you what is happening.  The executable `pdf2swf.exe` is trying to open `$file.pdf`, rather than the actual file name.

In PHP, you need double quotes "" for inline variable substitution.

```
echo exec("D:\wamp\www\dspzlibrary\converter\pdf2swf.exe books\$file.pdf -o books\$file.swf -f -T 9 -t -s storeallcharacters");
```

See: http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php

> The most important feature of double-quoted strings is the fact that variable names will be expanded.

Comment: Still no lock for now after "" double quotes